# Deleting Nodes of values in range x1 and x2 using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a function `DeleteNodes(T & val1, T & val2)` that deletes the nodes of values in range. An unhandled exception error occurs when I run my program. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in the implementation. I am using a defined function called `DeleteNode(T &val)` that deletes the desired node. Can anyone help me with this situation please?

```
void DLList<T>::DeleteNodes(T & val1 ,T & val2)
{
    if(IsEmpty())
        return;
    if(head == tail)
    {
        if(head->val >= val1 && head->val <= val2)
            DeleteHead();
    }

    DLLNode <T> *p;

    for(p = head ; p != NULL ; p  = p->next)
    {
        if(p->val >= val1 && p->val <= val2)
        {   T x = p->val;  
            DeleteNode(x);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more details about this 'unhandled' exception?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is DeleteNode doing? Why is there a difference between DeleteHead and DeleteNode? Is DeleteNode deleting the node that p is just pointing to so that p will be invalid after DeleteNode?

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, this is the first time for me to ask a question of this type,, i have to be more specific,for the DeleteNode(T & val) function it just delete one desired node , for the DeleteNodes(T & val1, T & val2) function it deletes all the nodes that have the value in range between val1 and val2, here is the DeleteNode() function :

```
bool DLList<T>::DeleteNode(T& val) 
{
bool found = false;

if(IsEmpty() == true)
    return false;

if(val == head->val)
{
    DeleteHead();
    return true;
}

if(val == tail->val)
{
    DeleteTail();
    return true;
}

DLLNode<T> *node, *predNode, *succNode;
node = predNode = succNode = NULL;

//Traverse list to find the node to be deleted
for(node = head->next; node != NULL; node = node->next)
{
    if(node->val == val)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found == true)
{
    // Unlink deleted node from list
    predNode = node->prev;
    succNode = node->next;
    predNode->next = node->next; 
    succNode->prev = node->prev;
    delete node;
}
return found;
}
```